# R - How does a for loop, that works pixel-wise, can be writen as lapply or foreach in order to enable parallel processing?

Tags: r, for-loop, foreach, parallel-processing, lapply

I'm working with BFAST, a **pixel-based** algorithm that detects breaks in time-series. My input raster data is an irregular NDVI time series and I'm aiming to firstly, smooth the irregular TS to monthly (16 years with 12 months each 16*12=**192**) and secondly apply the BFAST algorithm.

https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/bfast/index.html

http://bfast.r-forge.r-project.org/

Input dimensions: 488 rows, 985 columns, 181 layers (dates)

Output of smoothed TS: 488 rows, 985 columns, 192 layers (dates)

**Note:** My data have NA values around the boundaries because is subsetted with a shapefile to avoid the sea that surrounds the under-study island.

My code works like this:

1. Creates a raster stack object (of irregular frequency)
2. Recreates a georeferenced empty raster stack (NA values) named smoothed.time.series
3. Inside a for loop

   - takes a pixel and extracts the values of it throughout the years as a vector with dimensions rows=181 and columns=1.
   - checks if all the values in the vector are NA (see Note above) and if so it doesn't interact with the empty raster, replacing nothing.
   - if it finds that the percentage of NA values is not 100%, calculates the time series with irregular dates (bfastts returns a ts* object and is just a function inside the bfast package that I'm using). The s variable has dimensions rows=5813 cols=1 and just defines **when** are the available values acquired and puts NA everywhere else. 5813 is the number of days in the 16 year period that I'm working on.
   - Then with linear interpolation finds the daily time series (s.d.periodic) [replacing NA values so I have a complete time series]
   - Using a function and window() I find the monthly values and I define the start and end of the ts. Now the dimensions are rows=192 cols=1 (s.m.periodic.window)
   - Finally, I replace the NA values of the pixel along the third dimension [192 layers/dates] with my monthly aggregated data.

It works perfectly and I'm doing it this way because raster::calc() gave nothing but a hard time and a sequence of errors in the final dimensions. My problem now is that this for loop takes 2.82 seconds per pixel to aggregate it and replace the values. I'm using an existing empty raster stack because I've read that it is faster than creating a new layer/row/col in every loop. It will take approximately 12 days to complete, which is not convenient. **So how can I rewrite this for loop so that it can use all available cores and do parallel processing?**

```
# Functions
aggregate.daily.to.monthly <- function(daily.ts) {
  
  s.month <- round(aggregate(as.zoo(daily.ts), as.yearmon, median), 4)
  s.month <- as.ts(s.month)
  return(s.month)
}

catf <- function(..., file="log.txt", append=TRUE){
  cat(..., file=file, append=append)
}
```

**EDIT**
**Data entry**, providing a reproducible example.
Now let's say I have 8 NDVI indices (5x5 dimensions) in their respective dates and I want to find the missing monthly values starting 2000-Jan to 2001-Dec (709 days - 24 months).
I'm not setting NA values but let's say we have to check if there are vectors that have only NA and just ignore them.

```
dates <- as.POSIXct(strptime(c("2000-01-13","2000-05-21", "2000-09-03", "2000-11-24", "2001-02-24","2001-04-16","2001-08-02","2001-12-22"), "%Y-%m-%d"))
ndvi.empty <- raster(nrows=5, ncols=5, vals=NULL)
ndvi <- stack(lapply(1:8, function(i) setValues(ndvi.empty, runif(25, 0.1, 0.9)))) 
#ndvi variable is a 'RasterBrick' class
```

Interpolate to smoothed time series

```
empty.raster <- raster(nrows=nrow(ndvi),ncols=ncol(ndvi),vals=NULL)
smoothed.time.series <- stack(lapply(1:24, function(i) setValues(empty.raster,NA)))
#smoothed.time.series variable is a 'RasterStack' class


ncell<-length(ndvi$layer.1) #Like rows*cols, but not all elements, ncell=25 in this example

for (pixel in (1:ncell)) {
  pix.vec <- as.vector(ndvi[pixel])
  #[1] 0.7878372 0.4166008 0.3253537 0.2463029 0.5073630 0.3717476 0.6411799 0.6174676
  if (all(is.na(pix.vec))==FALSE) {
    s <- bfastts(pix.vec, dates, type = c("irregular"))
    #Time-Series [1:709] from 2000 to 2002: 0.788 NA NA NA ...
    s.d.periodic <- round(na.interp(s),4)
    #Time-Series [1:709] from 2000 to 2002: 0.788 0.785 0.782 0.779 ...
    s.m.periodic.window <- window(x = aggregate.daily.to.monthly(s.d.periodic), 
                                  start = c(2000,1), end = c(2001,12),
                                  frequency = 12)
    #Time-Series [1:24] from 2000 to 2002: 0.762 0.691 0.602 0.514 ...
    cat('Smoothing', pixel, 'of', ncell, '\n')
    smoothed.time.series[pixel][1:24]<-s.m.periodic.window[1:24]
#smoothed.time.series[25]    
#layer.1 layer.2 layer.3 layer.4 layer.5 layer.6 layer.7 layer.8 layer.9 layer.10
#[1,] 0.7617 0.6906 0.6022 0.5137 0.4253  0.3927 0.3667  0.3401  0.3124  0.2829
#layer.11 layer.12 layer.13 layer.14 layer.15 layer.16 layer.17 layer.18 layer.19
#[1,] 0.2573  0.3102  0.3967  0.4832  0.4489   0.391  0.4516  0.5276  0.6025
#layer.20 layer.21 layer.22 layer.23 layer.24
#[1,]  0.6387  0.6336  0.6285  0.6234  0.6191
  }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO!. What you do looks very inefficient. But to be able to help you, you would need to provide a working example. That is (a) example input data --- e.g. a RasterStack with a few cells, and (b) a function that takes a vector argument (representing a single cell);  and some example input and output data for that function (ideally from the cells of the RasterStack

Comment: A for loop is almost never the right answer in R and I don't see a  reason why you are using one (or why, in using one, you need to write to the console for each pass!).  There is certainly no reason to use a for loop find out if a vector is all NA values see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9417391/how-to-check-if-entire-vector-has-no-values-other-than-na-or-nan-in-r.

Comment: I'm sorry for my messy question, I'm using SO and R for a month now. I've corrected the NA check process as Elin suggested. As for the printing, I have to monitor the process somehow because it is quite lengthy. If my provided example is still inefficient for you to look into please inform me to provide some more data.